# How are the clones created in Star Wars

Tags: star-wars, clones

In Star Wars, has it been mentioned how the clone troopers & any other clones are created? By that I mean, was somatic cell nuclear transfer the method that was used?

Answer (score 3):

There's no description of the *process* by which clones are initiated in the films or any of the canon books, other than that donor DNA (courtesy of Jango Fett for the clone troopers) is required.

Interestingly, *fresh* infusions of DNA are evidently required on an ongoing basis in order to prevent the clones from becoming sluggish and incompetent.

> **Lama Su:** *Ever since the unfortunate Death of Jango Fett, we have had to stretch his DNA to produce more clones. However, I have noticed this unit of clones have been ... deficient*
>
> <sub><sup>[The Clones Wars: Arc Troopers](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=star-wars-the-clone-wars&episode=s03e01)</sup></sub>

---

Moving into the Legends canon, we have this description in the [Dark Force Sourcebook](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Dark_Empire_Sourcebook)

> Cloning takes a Human cell, and duplicates its genetic code. **The code
> is implanted in a cell and as the cell grows into a Human**, it will
> create an exact duplicate of the cell donor

Comment: I think also there has been no mention of clones being done as they are on earth where the embryo is implanted in a host and born, but all seem to have been done completely out of body so to speak.

Comment: @Scott.Bell - Yes, they use *cloning chambers*, evidently.